# facebook registration plugin location field not writing to mysql

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Everything else works fine except for the location.  The actual city/state does not come across.  Instead the word Array is displayed.  My field type in the database is text but I've tried every field type through mysql.  The HTML file is JSON where it comes to the field names.  I am very new at this so any help is appreciated.

This is my php file:

```
    <? ob_start(); ?>
 <?php
            define('FACEBOOK_APP_ID', '');
            define('FACEBOOK_SECRET', '');

            // No need to change function body
            function parse_signed_request($signed_request, $secret) {
                list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2);

                // decode the data
                $sig = base64_url_decode($encoded_sig);
                $data = json_decode(base64_url_decode($payload), true);

                if (strtoupper($data['algorithm']) !== 'HMAC-SHA256') {
                    error_log('Unknown algorithm. Expected HMAC-SHA256');
                    return null;
                }

                // check sig
                $expected_sig = hash_hmac('sha256', $payload, $secret, $raw = true);
                if ($sig !== $expected_sig) {
                    error_log('Bad Signed JSON signature!');
                    return null;
                }

                return $data;
            }

            function base64_url_decode($input) {
                return base64_decode(strtr($input, '-_', '+/'));
            }

            if ($_REQUEST) {
                $response = parse_signed_request($_REQUEST['signed_request'],
                                FACEBOOK_SECRET);
/*
                echo "<pre>";
                print_r($response);
                echo "</pre>"; // Uncomment this for printing the response Array
                */

                $name = $response["registration"]["name"];
                $email = $response["registration"]["email"];
                $gender = $response["registration"]["gender"];
                $prosecutor = $response["registration"]["prosecutor"];
                $location = $response["registration"]["location"];

                // Connecting to Database
                $con = mysql_connect("my_hosting_site","Database","password");
                if (!$response)
                  {
                  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
                  }

                mysql_select_db("Database", $con);

                mysql_query("INSERT INTO my_table (name, email, gender, prosecutor, location)
                VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$gender', '$prosecutor', '$location')");

                mysql_close($con);

            }
            $URL="https://www.facebook.com";

            header ("Location: $URL");
                    ?>
<? ob_flush(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Facebook

Basically, it's an array.

```
[location] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Delhi, India
                    [id] => 1.1604xxxxxx286E+14
                )
```

Use this for getting location stored in your db, like I have written below:

```
$location = $response["registration"]["location"]["name"];
```